# WebGL - drawElements: The texture is a non-power-of-two texture or not mipmap complete

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am drawing a `<video>` onto a webgl canvas. I have it working in chrome and firefox, but IE11 seems to be throwing an error. The error states:

```
drawElements: The texture is a non-power-of-two texture or not mipmap complete
```

and refers to this specific line:

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

I have a `requestAnimationFrame` loop running that is updating my canvas. I've read this error can be caused by the image not being ready or loaded. Here is my loop:

```
(function loop()
{
  if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended)
  {

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended)
    {
      try
      {
        // update the video frame
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, player);
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        log(e);
      }
    }

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vx);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vx_ptr, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ix);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
})();
```

What seems to be causing this? I have been searching with no luck. Before my loop runs, I setup the webgl canvas with this code:

```
 $scope.prepWebGL = function()
 {
      // prepare visible WebGL
      vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(vs, "attribute vec2 vx;varying vec2 tx;void main(){gl_Position=vec4(vx.x*2.0-1.0,1.0-vx.y*2.0,0,1);tx=vx;}");
      gl.compileShader(vs);

      ps = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(ps, "precision mediump float;uniform sampler2D sm;varying vec2 tx;void main(){gl_FragColor=texture2D(sm,tx);}");
      gl.compileShader(ps);

      shader  = gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(shader, vs);
      gl.attachShader(shader, ps);
      gl.linkProgram(shader);
      gl.useProgram(shader);

      vx_ptr = gl.getAttribLocation(shader, "vx");
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vx_ptr);
      gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "sm"), 0);

      vx = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vx);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      ix = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ix);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array([0,1,2, 0,2,3]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      tex = gl.createTexture();
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,     gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,     gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is actually that the video is not loaded, you could add a flag to your video, to indicate that the video is loaded

```
player.loaded = false;
player.onload = function() {
    this.loaded = true;
}
```

and then check if the video is loaded in your loop

```
if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended && player.loaded)
{
  try
  {
    // update the video frame
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, player);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the texture you are currently using is not a power of 2 and webgl has limited non power of 2 texture support. In particular, you cant generate mip maps with non power of 2 textures nor can you set them on repeat.

What is strange is that you are using `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);` which supposely do not use mip maps and you are using `gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE` as well. Perhaps it is a bug with IE?

Comment: I understood the error meaning the texture wasn't divisible by two. I need to know how to solve it. I've only been able to locate one working WebGL video demo in IE11: http://plugincc.fabiobiondi.com/assets/videogl/demo/ most of the other WebGL video demos do not work in IE11.

Comment: Try it with MIN_FILTER set to gl.NEAREST, try it with actual power of 2 textures (make your canvas power of 2), try it with gl.RGBA in texImage2D. If none of them work then you will have to experiment.

Comment: nope, neither worked. gl.NEAREST broke in all browsers. I didn't notice any difference between RGB and RGBA. I think this is a bug in IE11 that is going to take a long time to get fixed. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/927217/webgl-video-texture-support-is-broken-possible-regression

Comment: Well if the issue is that IE11 doesnt support video element then there is not much you can do. Perhaps draw the content of video element to a 2D canvas first and use that as the source?

Comment: I started with a 2d canvas, but for what I need to do (use getImageData and putImageData) there is a pretty big memory leak that eventually causes the browser to crash

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have some scale problem, but you may use video formats like 512*512 or 1024*512, that will solve your problem your compatibility problem, you can too include your video in a video in the correct size with some video converters or some video editing tools. In order to not lose the scale ratio of your source video